# Access Delegate Data

Tags: iphone, ios4

Hello i'm trying to make a simple ios app with tabs and navigation .

in the delegate i have the following type:

```
BlogRss * _currentlySelectedBlogItem;
```

with this property:

```
@property (readwrite,retain) BlogRss * currentlySelectedBlogItem;
```

and i'm trying to get his data with two other classes, one is a table view with the data and the other will show the data;
in both classes i have declared the following:

```
@class NewsAppDelegate;
NewsAppDelegate * _appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet _NewsAppDelegate * appDelegate;
@synthesize appDelegate = _appDelegate;
```

ofter "touching" the cell in the table view i wrote this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [[self appDelegate] setCurrentlySelectedBlogItem:[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
  //  [[self appDelegate] loadNewsDetails];

     NewsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[NewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
```

}

when i'm writing in the other class:

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.appDelegate.currentlySelectedBlogItem);
```

i'm getting null.

clearly i'm doing something wrong, but i don't know what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that this line is returning null:

```
[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Code is easier to debug when you don't nest so many sentences.

You can access your delegate from anywhere because UIApplication is a singleton, you don't need to keep a reference as you do with `self.appDelegate`. Example:

```
(NewsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Or just do as Jennis suggest, who is a faster typer than me, and remove the IBOutlet. :P

When you do

```
NewsAppDelegate * _appDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet _NewsAppDelegate * appDelegate;
@synthesize appDelegate = _appDelegate;
```

The result is the same if you skip the first line, because the runtime creates it for you.
See [Question about @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112283/a-doubt-about-synthesize/6112553#6112553). And I guess _NewsAppDelegate is really NewsAppDelegate (no underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Please do as follow.

```
//Your Header File 
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
{
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) YourAppDelegate *appDelegate;

@end

//Your Implementation file
@implementation YourViewController
@synthesize appDelegate

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}

@end
```

After declaring as above you will have access of appDelegate anywhere in your view controller.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks! I changed it like you said and now every thing is working great!

Comment: @user700230 Glad it worked for you. Please accept answer by clicking right sign with answer or upvote. Thanks.